# Proper use of conjunction Where

Tags: conjunctions

A statement read

> Today, mention of the word ‘Aadhaar’
>   would not lead a listener to the dictionary meaning of this word.
>   Instead, every person on the very mentioning of this word
>   ‘Aadhaar’ would associate it with the card that is issued to a
>   person **from where** he/she can be identified.

My doubt is: Here which refers to the **Aadhar Card** but to my mind **Aadhar** card is not some place 
Is this construction wrong?

Comment: You're quite right. Any sort of ID card is something ***by** (means of) **which*** someone can be identified.

Answer (score 1):

This construction:

> card that is issued to a person **from where** he/she can be identified

is not correct.

In fact it does not seem to be the original wording.

If the statement had been

> card that is issued to a person **whence** he/she can be identified

it would have been perfectly acceptable.

Let's try to understand the conditions *from which* this statement came. We can expect to learn more about English in the process.

I can think of two likely reasons that *from where* was used.

**First Possible Reason that *from where* is Used**

*Whence* is correct. However the word *whence* is uncommon as an adverb and as a conjunction.

[English tends to simplify over time (in a certain sense) which leads us to favor other constructions over the original matched adverbs *whence*, *hence*, *thence*.]

*Whence* or any other uncommon word might be removed from a text if the change in overall style pleased the writer or editor.

Let's think about what could happen if we overlook the causal meaning and (incorrectly!) consider *whence* to be equivalent to *from where* **in every case**.  This means we are only using *whence* directionally, ever.

This sort of (incorrect, but moderately effective) simplifying process could easily lead to a word processor rule that would automatically replace *whence* with *from where*.

Clearly there is some confusion between the directional/location usage and the causal/reason usage.

**Second Possible Reason that *from where* is Used**

It is possible the writer misunderstood *from where* as being capable of both roles.

Consulting a dictionary we can confirm there are many adverbs beginning in *where-*.  One example would be *whereto*.  *Whereto* does have a more general role.

Finally we can say that the confusion between location and reason *is the problem*.

Any wording which sets the card as *the reason for being identified* is correct.

Any wording that sets the card as *the location where identifying starts* is wrong.